# Объяснить фрагмент кода с struct

Tags: c++, указатели, struct

```
<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct list_ele {
    int data;
    struct list_ele* pointer;
} ar[3];

int main() {
    struct list_ele* lp;

    ar[0].data = 5;
    ar[0].pointer = &ar[1];
    ar[1].data = 99;
    ar[1].pointer = &ar[2];
    ar[2].data = -7;
    ar[2].pointer = NULL;

    lp = ar;

    while (lp) {
        cout << "contents " << lp->data << endl;
        lp = lp->pointer;
    }
}
```

я вроде со структурой знаком но такую запись вижу в первые, например мне не понятно почему массив ar объявлен за скобками и как он работает, а ещё внутри структуры не понята эта строка struct list_ele* pointer; и потом так-же указываем struct list_ele* lp; В общем не очень понятный код, прошу объясните если не сложно. Спасибо!

Comment: Это реализация односвязного списка с объявлением массива в качестве глобальной переменной. Подробнее: [указатели](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/4.1.php), [глобальные переменные](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/globalnye-peremennye), [односвязный список](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2022/02/11/c-linear-singly-linked-list-general-information-ru/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct list_ele {
    int data;
    struct list_ele* pointer;
} ar[3];
```

- 

```
int data - данные в списке
struct list_ele* pointer - указатель на следующий элемент списка
ar[3] - объявлении массива list_ele размерности 3 как глобальная переменная
```

Я так полагаю, здесь больше проблема в понимании работы списков или массивов, нежели в чем-либо еще

Это, как мне кажется, очень странно написанный код, но каждый элемент указывает на следующий в списке, то есть, обращаясь к `list->next_element` вы сможете обратиться к следующему элементу в списке

Пример:

```
//Допустим, объявили массив int[] a = new int[3]
a[2] = 1;
```

Эквивалентно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  a = a->pointer;
a->value = 1;
```

То есть за два шага цикла мы добрались до 3го элемента массива

Если вопрос состоит зачем здесь объявлен `ar[3]` - я не знаю. Вы и так сможете добраться до любого элемента списка и здесь объявление массива, как по мне, является ненужным костылем

Comment: похоже, это пайтонист написал связанный список на с++ )))

Comment: А ничего, что в c/c++ трёхмерные и вообще многомерные массивы запрещены?